# Java POI FormulaEvaluator giving unexpected floating point value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Java POI library to read an Excel file and then display it in HTML table. The Excel file is very simple with 1 row and 3 columns:

A1 cell= 21.7
B1 cell= 20.0
C1 cell is a formula cell with the formula =(A1-B1)/B1 and it has a custom format of "Percentage" with 0 decimal places. Excel displays its value as 9%. This is because 1.7/20 on a calculator gives result as 0.085; when it is converted to "Percentage" format it becomes 8.5% and because format says include 0 decimal places, it gets rounded up to 9%, so that's what Excel displays. All good.

However, POI displays the value as 8% instead. I observe that 1.7/20 is calculated to be 0.084999999. Because of the Percentage format as applied above it converts to 8.4999999% and because of 0 decimal places, it gets rounded down to 8%.

How can I have POI return me 9% instead of 8%? Here is the code snippet:

```
String myFormat="0%";
CreationHelper helper = wbWrapper.getWb().getCreationHelper();
CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT,helper.createDataFormat().getFormat(myFormat));
String val = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
```

Here evaluator is an instance of org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator and dataFormatter is an instance of org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter

When I print the variable "val" it is returning 8% instead of what is displayed in Excel (9%).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observations are correct. The problem occurs because of the general floating point problems. It can simply be shown:

```
...
System.out.println(1.7/20.0); //0.08499999999999999
System.out.println((21.7-20.0)/20.0); //0.08499999999999996
...
```

As you see, the division of double value 1.7 by double value 20.0 results in 0.08499999999999999. This would be fine since this value would be taken as 0.085 using `DecimalFormat`. But the more complex equation (21.7-20.0)/20.0 results in 0.08499999999999996. And this clearly is lower than 0.085 .

`Excel` tries solving those problems by an additional rule for floating point values. It always uses only 15 significant decimal digits of an floating point value. So `Excel` does something like :

```
...
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal((21.7-20.0)/20.0);
System.out.println(bd.round(new MathContext(15)).doubleValue()); //0.085
...
```

Neither `apache poi`'s  `FormulaEvaluator` nor it's `DataFormatter` behaves like `Excel` in this point. That's why the difference.

One could have an own `MyDataFormatter` where the only difference to [/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_1/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.java?view=markup) is:

```
...
    private String getFormattedNumberString(Cell cell, ConditionalFormattingEvaluator cfEvaluator) {
        if (cell == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Format numberFormat = getFormat(cell, cfEvaluator);

        double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        java.math.BigDecimal bd = new java.math.BigDecimal(d);
        d = bd.round(new java.math.MathContext(15)).doubleValue();

        if (numberFormat == null) {
            return String.valueOf(d);
        }
        String formatted = numberFormat.format(Double.valueOf(d));
        return formatted.replaceFirst("E(\\d)", "E+$1"); // to match Excel's E-notation
    }
...
```

Then using that `MyDataFormatter` instead of `DataFormatter` would be more compatible to `Excel`'s  behavior.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelEvaluateFormula {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook();
  CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = creationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0); cell.setCellValue(21.7);
  cell = row.createCell(1); cell.setCellValue(20.0);

  cell = row.createCell(2); cell.setCellFormula("(A1-B1)/B1");
  formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell); 
  double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();
System.out.println(d); //0.08499999999999996

  MyDataFormatter dataFormatter = new MyDataFormatter();

  String myFormat="0%";
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat(myFormat));
  String val = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
  System.out.println(val); //9%

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Axel, Thank you so very much for the detailed explanation. This is very very helpful. I really wish if it was possible to extend the org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter  class do I didn't have to duplicate it as MyFormatter.
Thank you again.