# POI DataFormatter Rounds 5 Down by default instead of Rounding Up

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In Apache POI, I'm trying to read an Excel spreadsheet that has a Cell (raw) value of: 0.575

From what I understand, the purpose of the `DataFormatter.formatCellValue()` method is to return cell's value in the way it is shown in the Excel document.

The Cell format in Excel is Custom: `"£"#,##0.00;[Red]-"£"#,##0.00`

The way it displays in Excel is: £0.58

when I use:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String displayValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```

I get: £0.57

Why is POI's formatter rounding down the value, when Excel rounds it up?

I've tried:

```
if( type == CellType.NUMERIC ) {
    Format format = formatter.getDefaultFormat(cell);
    if( format instanceof DecimalFormat ) {
        DataFormatter.setExcelStyleRoundingMode((DecimalFormat)format);
    }
}
```

But the Rounding mode doesn't get set, because the `format` is `ExcelGeneralNumberFormat`.  One of the members of `format` is a DecimalFormat (as I can see from the debugger), but it seems I don't have API access to it.

I believe this is related:  When I inspect the XML value of the cell, I see:

```
<xml-fragment r="D1" s="2">
  <main:v>0.57499999999999996</main:v>
</xml-fragment>
```

Which is of course different to the "raw" value I see in Excel (0.575).
If the POI framework is rounding 0.57499999999999996 and not 0.575 then that of course explains why it's rounding down and not up.
The only way to reproduce the behaviour of Excel then, is to Round the raw value to 3dp (0.575) - then round *again* to 2dp (0.58)

Comment: Is it truncating? What happens to 0.579?

Comment: you're right, it's not truncating, but it's rounding down from 5 rather than up (as Excel does) - question edited

Comment: 3.17 is very old, you could try a more recent version.

Comment: I tried again with 5.0.0 - same result

Comment: `0.5749999` rounded to 2dp is 0.57 not 0.58. Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point...

Comment: @Gagravarr you mean welcome to the wonderful world of Excel - Excel displays it as 0.58!

Comment: `Excel` only uses 15 significant digits of floating point values in its GUI. And the value gets rounded while truncating to 15 digits. So for `Excel` GUI it is 0.575. `Apache poi` does not have that behavior up to now.

Comment: Thank you @AxelRichter - so this is what POI's formatter needs to truly reflect what's shown in Excel

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664120/java-poi-formulaevaluator-giving-unexpected-floating-point-value/58669576#58669576